# How to automatically refresh PDF viewer?

Tags: pdf, texmaker

I am a beginner in LaTex. My friend recommends me the TeXMaker. However, I don't know how to automatically refresh the "View PDF" section. It would be really convenient if I can write on left and see the output on the right. I can see the output in the right hand now, but

1. It does not make any change if I change anything in the "quick build, even after I click the arrow next to the "View PDF"
2. How can the output on the right hand automatically change if there is anything changed?

I appreciate if anyone can help me!

P.S.: I am a MacBook user.

[image: Here is the setting I currently have in preference]

Comment: I would recommend TexStudio which is a fork of TexMaker with some nice extra features. There the standard configuration is F5 for compile+view, F6 just compile and F7 just view, the latter being very convenient when having multiple documents open or when you want to jump to the current position in the PDF. On the fly is not possible since LaTeX needs to compile.  LyX might be an alternative for you.

Comment: This is the only reason I changed my editor from TeXmaker to TexStudio. I think, you try to use it since it has many common layout as TeXmaker.

Comment: TeXmaker doesn't do automatic refresh. You need 'Quick build'  which combine several commands. When you choose 'pdflatex+view pdf' it will run 'pdflatex' compiler and then 'view pdf'.

Comment: If you can install okular, you would be able to see all changes just after compilation.

Comment: `on the fly`-viewing is neither supported by TeXstudio or TeXmaker. it is in `gummi` (linux tool) or `TeXpad` (Mac OS X). AFAIK it has been requested to be a feature in TXS resp. TXM

Answer (score 1):

Since you are a MacBook/macOS user, the *Preview.app* should satisfy your requirements.

In the "preferences" settings, disable the usage of 'Built-in Viewer' by activation of 'External Viewer'. The given default command *`'open %.pdf'`* should work. If it doesn't, use *`'open -a /Applications/Preview.app %.pdf'`* instead.