# automatically refresh pdf preview when compiling texmaker with arara

Tags: compiling, texmaker, arara

I am using texmaker and I am compiling using arara. I need to set the pdf preview of the texmaker to refresh automatically and set the cursor on the same position of the code.

This is my arara compilation in the document:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: bibtex
% arara: makeindex
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
```

and I am using the quick build command of texmaker set to user command:

```
arara %.tex
```

Comment: Try `% arara: pdflatex: { synctex: on }`

Comment: this worked for sync between the source code and the pdf file, but the pdf file is not opening and refreshing and automatically, I have to click on view pdf and jump to pdf from the code. any thoughts to have it working like it is when compiling with pdflatex?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't use TeXMaker. The `synctex` option was just a guess based on how it's done with TeXworks, but judging from the comments on [How to automatically refresh pdf viewer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301483/how-to-automatically-refresh-pdf-viewer) it seems that the quick build first runs `pdflatex` and then does 'view pdf'. I don't know how you'd change the quick build to run `arara` instead of `pdflatex`.

Comment: I have changed the quick build command of texmaker to use arara.. but I need to know how to view the pdf after compilation